# Sitecore 7 - Multilist with search relative path

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Given the following structure

```
Home
    Storage
        Article1
        Article2
        Article3
    Products
        Product
```

Where the item `product` has a `Multilist with search` field that targets the item `storage`. How do I set the *StartSearchLocation* relative to product?

I've tried the following

```
StartSearchLocation=query:[parent::item[@@templatename=Home]]/Storage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following to the `Source` field of the template;

```
query:ancestor-or-self:: *[@@templatename = 'home']/*[@@templatename = 'storage']/*
```

This will look for the ancestor (or iteself) that's template is Home, then looks for a child of home that has the is a template of storage. Then it will select all items underneath storage.

You can even go a step further and ensure it only selects items under storage that are articles;

```
query:ancestor-or-self:: *[@@templatename = 'home']/*[@@templatename = 'storage']/*[@@templatename = 'articles']
```

Although I wouldn't recommend using `templatename`, rather `Templateid` for example;

```
query:ancestor-or-self:: *[@@templateid = '{96563B8C-A000-488C-B7E2-96008C24F3D3}']/*[@@templateid = '{0E47CA9D-E762-4FDF-8C6C-C500DD9EB40A}']/*[@@templateid = '{0E47CA9D-E762-4FDF-8C6C-C500DD9EB40A}']
```

Don't forget to replace my `Guids` with yours

Comment: http://blog.navigationarts.com/multilist-with-search-bug-in-sitecore-7-2-rev-141226/ Looks like I've encountered a bug! Will add the hotfix. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!